# Laravel many to many relation not working

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to fetch data from a relationship but only relationship properties are returned.

**User Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable { 
      use SoftDeletes; use Notifiable; 

       /** 
        * The attributes that are mass assignable. 
        * 
        * @var array 
        */ 
        protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'email', ]; 

       /* 
        * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays. 
        * 
        * @var array 
        */ 
       protected $hidden = [ 'password', 'remember_token' ]; 

       /* 
        * Get the images for the store. 
        */ 
        public function stores() { 
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Store', 'store_user'); 
        }
}
```

**Stores Model**

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

**Pivot Table**

```
public function up() {
    Schema::dropIfExists('store_user');
    Schema::create('store_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('store_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Existing relations between pivot table and `id`s are accurate.

**Retrieving relations**

```
$user = Auth::user();
$userStores = $user->stores;
$storesID = [];
foreach ($userStores as $store) {
    $storesID[] = $store->id;
}
$builder->whereIn('store_id', $storesID);
```

This returns:

> Undefined property: App\User::$stores

I tried

```
$userStores = $user->stores()->get();
```

but that freezes the page until it throws a request took more than 60 seconds error.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what does `$user->stores()->toSql();` show?

Comment: dd($userStores = $user->stores
) plz

Comment: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded.    :(

Comment: @MahdiYounesi , that returns : Undefined property: App\User::$stores

Comment: what about `$user` ?

Comment: You can compact that block of code into:

    `$builder->whereIn('store_id', Auth::user()->stores->pluck('id'));`

Comment: @btl  sure will but still I cant retrieve user()->stores cause `Undefined property: App\User::$stores`

Comment: @MahdiYounesi it returns the User object

Comment: @MaroParo please show full `User` model class

Comment: class User extends Authenticatable
 { 
     use SoftDeletes; 
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the images for the store.
     */
    public function stores()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Store', 'store_user');
    }
} `

Comment: `$builder` can you include the code where that variable is being created in your question?

Comment: @btl I'm trying to get the stores in a Global Scope In the App\Scopes namespace I did not include the code because it's pretty basic except the apply function body

Comment: @btl the `$builder` is object of  `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`

Comment: Ok, youre sure then that its not part of the problem? I just wanted to rule out any possibilities.

Comment: @btl I'm sure. :/

Comment: Can you try renaming your `stores` relationship to something silly like `abcd`?

Comment: @NikolaGavric  I already did. No luck :(

Comment: Can you post your full stacktrace to https://paste.laravel.io/

Comment: Can you help me on how to do that @NikolaGavric?

Comment: Go to your `storage/logs/laravel.log` and remove everything, then trigger `Undefined property: App\User::$stores` and then go back to that log file and copy its contents into https://paste.laravel.io/

Comment: @NikolaGavric https://paste.laravel.io/8fecaca4-2b32-435c-94f0-c8e4397156bd#71-72,74

Comment: This is where your error pops out, give us that code `/Users/germancomputer/PhpstormProjects/ital_restaurant/app/Scopes/OwnerScope.php:28)`

Comment: @NikolaGavric the error is on dd()  public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        dd($userStores = $user->stores);
        $builder->whereIn('store_id', Auth::user()->stores()->pluck('id'));
    }

Comment: Are you using `global scopes`?

Comment: Yes @NikolaGavric

Comment: You need to show us the contents of `app/Scopes/OwnerScope.php` file and also show us the full code of the function where `$builder->whereIn('store_id', $storesID);` that line is

Comment: use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class OwnerScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        dd($userStores = $user->stores);
        $builder->whereIn('store_id', Auth::user()->stores()->pluck('id'));  
    }
}

Comment: Please update your question with both code from your scope and full code where you use `$builder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is 100% inside of your `OwnerScope` file, you should review that file first and then review the line where you assigned `$builder` it's value, I can't be of more help because you didn't include code from either so it's all we can do until you update your question and include both.

Comment: Thanks man ... I did some studying and found out this was the reason. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like $user is not logged in, maybe check first with:

```
if (Auth::check()) {

}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. If $user was not logged in, it would give you the error that you're trying to access a property on null.